# Variable Not a CFString

Tags: cfstring

I am using a database to populate a table view.

I created an `NSMutable Array` of object in the `AppDelegate`. The Array is populated from the DB as follows:

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sql = "select barcode, vintage, vineyard, varietal from wine";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *barcode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            DBHelper *wineObj = [[DBHelper alloc] initWithBarcode:barcode];
            wineObj.vintage = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
            wineObj.vineyard = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            wineObj.varietal = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

            [appDelegate.wineList addObject:wineObj];
            [wineObj release];
        }
    }
}
```

All of the data goes into the array correctly with barcode being of type `NSString *`. However, when the table view is displayed, the barcode turns into "`Variable Not a CFString`." When I select an item, I am using:

```
//get the bottle details for selected object
DBHelper *tempObj = [appDelegate.wineList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
DBHelper getBottleDetails:[appDelegate getDBPath]:tempObj.barcode];
```

Because the barcode is not longer being interpreted as an `NSString`, the app crashes. How do I ensure that the barcode remains valid to use?